# Custom validation for reactive forms

Tags: angular

Sharing Error and Entry Screen
I m exploring Custom Validation in Angular2. And gone through below article:
http://www.kirjai.com/validation-model-driven-forms-ng2/

When i configured and i typed any value in email text and getting below exception:

> TypeError: _this.subscribe is not a function
>       at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:58877:15
>       at new ZoneAwarePromise (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:62806:29)
>       at Object.toPromise (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:58875:12)
>       at _convertToPromise (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:4313:187)
>       at Array.map (native)
>       at FormControl.asyncValidator (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:4306:80)
>       at FormControl.AbstractControl._runAsyncValidator (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:16916:41)
>       at FormControl.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:16890:22)
>       at FormControl.setValue (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:17146:14)
>       at DefaultValueAccessor.onChange (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:5914:17)

Below is my component code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormControl, AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
selector: 'form-validation',
  templateUrl :'./app.validationform.html'
    })
    export class FormValidationComponent {
  validateForm : FormGroup;
  email: AbstractControl;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){
      this.validateForm = fb.group({

      'firstName' : [null, Validators.required],

      'email':[null, Validators.required,     Validators.compose([this.checkIfA])]

    })

    this.email = this.validateForm.controls['email'];
  }

    checkIfA(fieldControl: FormControl): { [s: string]: boolean }{
      console.log("filedControlValue",fieldControl.value[0]==='a');
      console.log("fieldControl.value",fieldControl.value[0]);
      console.log("returnValue",fieldControl.value[0] === 'a' ? null : {     notA: true });
     return fieldControl.value[0] === 'a' ? null : {notA: true };
    }

  submitForm(value: any){
    console.log(value);
  }
}
```

Below is my HTML COde:

```
<form [formGroup]="validateForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(validateForm.value)">
    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!validateForm.controls['firstName'].valid && validateForm.controls['firstName'].touched}">
        <label>First Name:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="FirstName" [formControl]="validateForm.controls['firstName']">
        <!-- The hasError method will tell us if a particular error exists -->
        <div *ngIf="validateForm.controls['firstName'].hasError('required') && validateForm.controls['firstName'].touched" class="alert alert-danger">You must include a first name.</div>
    </div>
              <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!email.valid && email.dirty && email.touched}">
        <label>Email</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email" [formControl]="email">
        <!-- The hasError method will tell us if a particular error exists -->
        <div *ngIf="email.hasError('required') && email.touched" class="alert alert-danger">You must include a email address.</div>
        <div *ngIf="email.hasError('notA') && email.touched" class="alert alert-danger">First letter of the email needs to be an a.</div>
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!validateForm.valid">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

[image: Error]

[image]

Comment: Also can  see code in jsfiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/kaet1wzn/1/

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple validators you must declare and array

'email':[null, Validators.required,   Validators.compose([this.checkIfA])]

this will be

'email':[null, [Validators.required, Validators.compose([this.checkIfA])]]